# Ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException при вызове prepare() на MediaPlayer

Tags: android, mediaplayer

долго мучаюсь с этой проблемой, смотрю много видео туторилов, у некоторых даже prepare() не надо вызывать и все работает. Получается вот код вызова:

```
trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(this, trackUri);

            player.prepareAsync();
            player.prepare();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            totalTime = player.getDuration();
            player.setLooping(true);
            sb.setMax(totalTime);
            player.start();
```

выскакивает `java.lang.IllegalStateException` на `prepare()`

Comment: `player.prepareAsync();` не должен вызываться вместе с `player.prepare();`, выберете что-то одно

Comment: Я попробовал удалить `player.prepareAsync();` выдавалась та же ошибка, удалил `player.prepare();` Запускается, но теперь выдает `error (-38, 0)`

Comment: Весь код после `setOnCompletionListener` Вам нужно поместить в обработку `onPrepared`